# How to do a recursive ( foreach loop ) using include tag ? Tree Structure-JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

**i would like to know if it possible that a JSP (boucle.jsp) include itself when a condition is true**

*this code trow me **java.lang.StackOverflowError** exception*

```
<% 
  for(Callers ck : calls.get(calls.size()-1)){
      pageContext.setAttribute("ck", ck);
      System.out.print("Test1 " +ck);
      if (app.hasChild(ck)== true) {
            c = app.childOf(ck);
            calls.add(c);
            %>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="c<%=i%>" /> 
            <label class="tree_label"for="c<%=i%>">${ck}<></label>
            <%i++;%>
            
             <%@include file="/Pclink/boucle.jsp" %>
            </li>
            <%
            }else {
                %>
                <li><span class="tree_label">${ck}</span></li>
                <%
            }
  }
calls.remove(calls.size()-1);
%>
</ul>*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , include is a static import , wich means the first thing happends is :
**<%@include file="/Pclink/boucle.jsp" %>**
brings the content of  "Pclink/boucle.jsp " and it put it in our jsp and because boucle.jsp call it selfs so it include it again and again ...

so what we need is a dynamique inclule which is **<jsp:include page="boucle.jsp" />**
NB: the boucle.jsp in that case must be a full jsp page not only a part of the code that u want it to be recursive;

and if you want to reach data from boucle.jsp
all u have to do is  puch data from the initial jsp with
request.setAtrribute("name_ that you_want_to_call_it ",variable);

and u catch it in boucle.jsp with
variable = request.getAttribute("name_ that you_called_it ");

however i'm not tooo good at english , i hope understand something.